# difficulty in matrix operation with Log data

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, formatting

I have a `code`:

```
(**********)
(* PART 1 *)
(**********)

Clear[z, n, d, t, \[Lambda], \[Psi], G, gBar, dataX, dataY, trs, abs, 
  logDataX, innovatorsAdjMatX, innovationIndexX, logDataY, 
  innovatorsAdjMatY, innovationIndexY, innovators, mu];
SeedRandom[19];

(* parameters *)
z = 1; (* time index for simulations *)
n = 15;
d = 0.2;
T = 7; 
\[Lambda] = 0.6;
\[Psi] = 2;
gBar = 0.05;

(* raw data *)
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges -> True,
   VertexLabels -> "Name"]; (* an adjacency digraph/system *)
dataX = Array[RandomInteger[{1, 8}] &, {n, T}]; 
dataY = Array[RandomInteger[{1, 8}] &, {n, T}]; 
{trs, abs} = {Table[{RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, n}], Table[{RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, n}]};

innovators[m_][k_] := ArrayPad[Transpose[{Unitize[m[[All, k]]]}], {0, {Dimensions[m][[1]] - 1, 0}}, "Fixed"]; (* by @kglr *)
mu[m_][k_] := MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, \[Lambda]*(m[[All, k]]/gBar)^\[Psi]];  (* by @kglr *)

logDataX = With[{A = Log[dataX]}, Clip[Subtract[A[[All, 2 ;;]], 
    A[[All, ;; -2]]], {gBar, \[Infinity]}, {0., 0.}]]; (* by @Henrik *)
innovatorsAdjMatX = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*Flatten[innovators[logDataX] /@ {z}, 1];   
innovationIndexX = Flatten[mu[logDataX] /@ {z}, 1];  

logDataY = With[{A = Log[dataY]}, Clip[Subtract[A[[All, 2 ;;]], 
    A[[All, ;; -2]]], {gBar, \[Infinity]}, {0., 0.}]];
innovatorsAdjMatY = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*Flatten[innovators[logDataY] /@ {z}, 1];   
innovationIndexY = Flatten[mu[logDataY] /@ {z}, 1];


(**********)
(* PART 2 *)
(**********)
Clear[edgeCapMat, information, infoX, infoY, sysX, sysY, sysXreduced, 
  sysYreduced, capTA, dataXY, dTA, dXY, dTAxi, dXYxi, dTAyi, dXYyi, 
  relocationSizeX, relocationSizeY];

(* constructing a weighted G *)
edgeCapMat[trsCap_, absCap_] := trsCap.Transpose[absCap];
information[stock_] := DiagonalMatrix[stock];
{infoX, infoY} = {dataX[[All, z]], dataY[[All, z]]};  
{sysX, sysY} = {information[infoX].edgeCapMat[trs, abs], 
   information[infoY].edgeCapMat[trs, abs]};
{sysXreduced, sysYreduced} = {AdjacencyMatrix[G]*sysX, AdjacencyMatrix[G]*sysY};

{capTA, dataXY} = {Table[{trs[[i]], abs[[i]]}, {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[{{dataX[[All, z]][[i]]}, {dataY[[All, z]][[i]]}}, {i, 1, n}]}; 
{dTA, dXY} = {Outer[EuclideanDistance, capTA, capTA, 1]*AdjacencyMatrix[G], 
   Outer[EuclideanDistance, dataXY, dataXY, 1]*AdjacencyMatrix[G]}; 
{dTAxi, dXYxi} = {dTA*innovatorsAdjMatX, dXY*innovatorsAdjMatX};
{dTAyi, dXYyi} = {dTA*innovatorsAdjMatY, dXY*innovatorsAdjMatY}; 

(* by @kglr *)
relocationSizeX = Quiet[Total[#, 1]/Total[Unitize[#], 1] &[(dXYxi/innovationIndexX[[All, -1]]) + dTAxi]] /. {Indeterminate -> 0}
relocationSizeY = Quiet[Total[#, 1]/Total[Unitize[#], 1] &[(dXYyi/innovationIndexY[[All, -1]]) + dTAyi]] /. {Indeterminate -> 0}
```

The output from this `code` (consider only the output of `relocationSizeX`):

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

This output is not correct. The correct one should be:

```
{0, 0, 0.4972, 0, 0.3305, 0}
```

because I made the calculations by hand using the following three matrices generated by the above `code`:

[image]

A second simpler example below generates the correct output generated only by **PART 2**. This implies that the problem lies in **PART 1**, but I cannot find where the problem is.

```
Quiet[Total[#, 1]/Total[Unitize[#], 1] &[(aa1/mum[[All, -1]]) + bb1]]
```

using the following data:

[image]

The output is correctly calculated as `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: could you write the `DXxi` and `DTAxi` matrix in mathematica format - too many numbers there.

Comment: @Sumit: I will do so immediately. Thanks.

Comment: I assume trailing X in `innovationIndexX` is a typo and I remove that. You can see `{{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}/{{g,h,i},{j,k,l}}[[All,-1]]` divides each row of the first matrix by the last element of the corresponding row of the second matrix. Since `innovationIndex[[All,-1]]` contains 8 trailing zeros there are 8 division by zeros and thus 8 rows of `Indeterminate`. `Total[#, 1]` adds `Indeterminate` to the sum that makes the sum `Indeterminate` which I think is why you see what you see..

Comment: Perhaps if we edit your post to show precisely your step by step manual calculation and then MMA's step by step calculation then we might be able to expose exactly where you and MMA are assuming and doing different things.

Comment: @Bill: I have edited my earlier question with the actual `code` generating the incorrect output. I also indicated that PART 1 in the `code` is the place where the potential mistakes lie.